# I have a mobile app that produces lots of data and I wish to make it available to everyone

Tags: web-hosting, non-profit, data-storage

My app produces geo-spatial data which I can host on my servers, but I also wish to give this data away to the open data community, does any one know of a hosting organization where I can create a website, and offer the data and incur no expenses on my part?

Comment: why not you make a website from any freelance website. You will find a lot out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com)?  It looks like it might accept datasets, although you wouldn't build a website there; the data would be accessible through their existing site.

Comment: This from a freebase expert: "This is just my personal opinion, but I'd say that pothole data is probably a little more fine-grained than Freebase traditionally deals with, but probably not completely out of bounds."